# How to use Spring Function’s Deployer with AWS Lambda

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

is there any sample or documentation for implement `@EnableFunctionDeployer` annotation for AWS Lambda.

I can't see any sample or doc for it.